# How to copy network security key from wifi

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, login, internet-connection

When I was at a customer site, I connected my Windows-10 computer to a Wifi. Now, every time I go there, I don't need to enter anything anymore, I can just connect to that Wifi.

Now I have a colleague who wants to connect to that Wifi too, and I would like to pass him that key. Where is it stored on my computer?

**Edit** In the meantime I check the entire registry, I didn't find anything.

The Wireless network I'm talking about has been configured, but it is not the network I'm working on now. While checking the network and sharing centre, I am able to work on the current network and to setup a new one, but where do I need to go in order to obtain information from the existing ones?

Hereby a screenshot of where I currently am: I am connected to "Telenet-34919", but I would like to obtain information from another Wifi:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah, "registry".... So probably Windows then?

Comment: @mtak: Yes, sorry, I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: So your customer gave you in confidence the password for you personally, and he did not give that password to your colleague?  And you just spread the password to others? I would advise your customer to change his password and not give it to you again. If that customer allows your colleague on the network, **he** should give him the password, not you! If your customer finds out you have been spreading passwords, he might request disciplinary actions. DO NOT DO THIS!!

Comment: @LjmDullaart: it's not like that: the customer gave me that information with the whole idea of me passing that information to my colleagues. I, however, instead of writing it down, I entered it in my PC, now it's there somewhere and I want to know where in order to be able to pass it through, just as intended.

Comment: Try  :netsh wlan show profile name="Profile Name"   key=clear to see password

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WirelessKeyView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) from Nirsoft to list all the WiFi access points you've connected to and their associated saved password. You don't need to install anything, just run the provided executable.

[image]

It's worth noting that both Windows Defender and Microsoft SmartScreen will flag the application as potentially malicious - this is because you can use the tool to extract a WiFi password that you wouldn't normally have had easy access to.

Comment: I'm sorry, but a password-protected zipfile with the password written just under the zipfile, not being recognised as a virus but being recognised as a virus when unzipping, ..., it looks too dangerous for me. I prefer solutions without all alarm bells ringing on my computer.

Comment: @Dominique Fair enough, most virus scanners will flag it as a HackTool which is defined as a "program designed to assist hacking" - which pretty much describes your need to extract a saved WiFi password from a machine.

Comment: Nirsoft is a very respected authority on Windows. His utilities have been advised in many posts on our site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no key to pass - only the password is required.

To display the password for an SSID, run the Command Prompt (CMD)
and enter the following command:

```
netsh wlan show profile "SSID" key=clear | findstr "Key Content"
```

To show the names of all your stored credentials:

```
netsh wlan show profile
```

Comment: Nice! Someone with better batch skills than me could probably whip something up that lists all the access points and associated WiFi password.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-your-wi-fi-network-password-in-windows-2ec74b2e-d9ec-ade1-cc9b-bef1429cb678):

- In Network and Sharing Center, next to Connections, select your Wi-Fi network name.
- In Wi-Fi Status, select Wireless Properties.
- In Wireless Network Properties, select the Security tab, then select the Show characters check box.
- Your Wi-Fi network password is displayed in the Network security key box.

Comment: I added a screenshot from the network and sharing centre, where to go from there?

Comment: Click on the `Wi-Fi (telenet-34919)`, which is _your Wi-Fi network name_ that's _next to connections_

Comment: I've done that, but this gives me the information of the network I'm currently connected to. I would like to have that information from another wifi.

Comment: Please review the Help Center on how to ask a good question. Important here is that _specific questions_ get _specific answers_ https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I'm sorry you misread, but I clearly mentioned what I wanted, didn't I?

Comment: First of all, you didn't specify that it needed to be on Windows, making me write a complete answer which turned out to be completely useless, wasting my time. Second, you could've made it much more clear in your original question that you aren't connected to this WiFi network now.

Comment: I see your point. Especially the fact that I forgot to mention not being connected there now is important indeed. Now that we sorted that out, do you have an idea how to answer my question?

Comment: No. While off topic, I would like to clarify: If you can't even be bothered to include these kind of details in your question, making me waste my time on answers that don't answer your intended (but not specified) question, I am not going to waste more of _my_ time to solve _your_ issue. Another suggestion: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before